# MySQL replication alternatives

Tags: php, mysql, synchronization, replication

I'm using Curl to send information between local and remote MySQL databases in order to keep them synchronised.

Each row that is sent keeps record of wether or not it has been updated in the central database, and keeps a record of the central database id for its transaction.

Is there a better way to keep many local databases synchronised with a central remote server?

PS I cannot use database replication because of shared hosting server restrictions.

Comment: You mentioned you can't use db replication. Can you explain why ? It could help understand better your context and find a solution.

Comment: @alfalloujiI cannot use database replication because of shared hosting server restrictions, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps consider a hosting provider that does allow you to use the most appropriate tool for the job

Comment: @MarkBaker that would be the best option, but considering the current circumstances  what would be a viable alternative?

Answer (score -1):

You have not really answered Alfallouji's question. Nor have you said anything about any of the contraints to your approach.

You said you want to replicate the data somewhere else, when the primary database is the hosted solution. What access is there to 'somewhere else' from the hosted server? Does somewhere else have a static IP address? Is it always up?

Can you access the binary log on the primary server?

How much replication lag can you accomodate?

There are lots of solutions.....mysql_proxy, mysql's built-in asynchronous replication (optionally with manual copying of replication logs). Multi-master replication. Or at the device level with DRBD, or write a custom dump tool and rsync the results.....

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Local databases don´t have static ips nor are they always up.  I cannot access binary log in the primary server.  Replication lag should be less than a couple of minutes.

Comment: You can't have low lag with low availability on the remote database. No matter how you replicate the data.

Comment: I'll look into your suggestions. Thanks.